# NIC interfaces and physical ports

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I have a physical server with 4 network ports and 3 network cables attached to port1 , port2 and port3. OS is Centos 6 and it has 4 files `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2` and `eth3`. Are these files matched with physical ports? I mean if I want to bond port1 and port3 should I config `eth0` and `eth2`? What happens if I create a file named for example `eth12` and config my network in `eth12`?

Comment: Can you paste here content of configuration files?

Comment: what would be the content of (at least one of the files)? It's also dependant on what service is managing the network. My guess would be that the physical interface is specified in a parameter in the file.

Comment: @BlackCrystal Please edit the post and paste the content of file there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long-standing problem, and in RHEL 7, [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) were introduced to solve it.

But for RHEL 6.x, unfortunately you'll have to verify which `ethN` number corresponds to which physical port on your own. If all your NICs use the same driver module, the ordering on a fresh installation is fairly deterministic: depending on the driver module, it will typically be by the NIC's PCI device order, or by MAC address order.

If you have two different NIC drivers, it will depend on which driver was initially loaded first.

When a new NIC is seen for the first time, its MAC address will be recorded in the respective `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*` file  with the `HWADDR=` keyword, and in the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file, and from that point on, if the drivers are loaded in a different order, the system will reassign the `eth*` names to keep the physical NIC on the same `eth*` name until the administrator changes it.

Note that there are two locations with the `eth*`-MAC relationship: if you change just one of them, strange things may happen.

If you're physically at the system, you can use `ethtool -p ethN` to help you identify each NIC: the command will make the specified NIC blink its LEDs in some distinctive way, if at all possible for that NIC model.

Dual- and quad-port NICs usually have consecutive MAC addresses for their ports; that can sometimes help in identifying which port is which.