# Is there a way to figure out what physical port a drive is being inserted into through linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, partition, usb-drive, port

Without knowing the order of which drives are being inserted and which ports they are being inserted (by human eye), is there a way to tell where they are being inserted using linux commands? I need this to be able to create a web design showing placement of ports & status etc.

Comment: if you are asking about network ports this might be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474479/nic-interfaces-and-physical-ports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. `lsusb` will give you details at the `Bus` and `Device` level and with `fdisk -l` it is possible to view which 'USB drives' are mapped into what devices. You can also look at the `dmesg` outputs to see the port in which your 'USB' has been plugged in. You may have to constantly checking the output.

For example:

```
>> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b2db Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:07a8 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport (WDBBEP), My Passport for Mac (WDBLUZ)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My external drive has been plugged in to my `USB3.0` port.

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    411647    409600   200M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     411648 126240767 125829120    60G Linux root (x86-64)
/dev/sda3  126240768 143017983  16777216     8G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  143017984 976773127 833755144 397.6G Linux root (x86-64)

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000170586112 bytes, 1953458176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00023f15

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953458175 1953456128 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

In the above, my external drive is `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: If you have multiple devices connected then what are the defining numbers/pieces of information that links what you get into lsusb and fdisk -l ? or do you just have to search through by insertion order?

Comment: going off that I guess what is the determining line or piece of info within lsusb that makes it usb3?